# How to control display of state_province field from the address module

Tags: webforms, 9

Ok - the title is not terribly clear.
I'm building a form that uses Advanced Address. That element comes from the Address module.
I want to control the display, or perhaps a better way of saying it; I want to suppress the display of the State/Province input field unless one of three countries is selected.

I'm pretty sure there are multiple ways of going about it. I'm looking for the cleanest. Maybe there is even an admin UI I've missed.

Out of the box, the State Province field is already conditional (e.g., it is not displayed until a country with states/provinces is selected- meaning:
Select

- Albania => no State box
- Canada => Province box with a contextual
  dropdown.

So - My goal is to simply suppress the state box for all but three countries.